# What is an auxiliary density/distribution?

Tags: regression, distributions, least-squares, blue, auxiliary-variable

I am currently reading an academic paper where, without definition, the concept of an "auxiliary distribution" has been invoked. Additional expressions used are "auxiliary density function" and "auxiliary model"

I have been googling and I can't find any definitions for these expressions. I am familiar with the general concept of an auxiliary function -- functions that are constructed in order to advance a mathematical proof. But I'm not sure what it would mean to have an "auxiliary density function," as my current understanding is that density function of an R.V. is uniquely determined.

Does anyone know how to interpret this? Here as an example quote, for context:

Suppose that the joint distribution $F(\textbf y)$ of the $n \times 1$ random vector  $\textbf Y$ has a density  $f(\textbf y )$ with bounded support $\mathscr Y$. Without loss of generality assume that the true coefficient equals $\beta_0=0$ and that  $\sigma^2=1.$

Because $\textbf Y$ has bounded support $\mathscr Y$ there is a set $B \subset \mathbb R^m$ such that  $|\textbf y' \Sigma^{-1}\textbf X \beta|<1$ for all $\beta \in B $ and $\textbf y \in \mathscr Y$.
For such values of $\beta$, define the auxiliary density function

$f_{\beta} (\textbf y) = f(\textbf y)(1+ \textbf y' \Sigma^{-1}\textbf X \beta)$

Comment: Doesn't this question literally answer itself?  The formula on the last line is the definition, exactly as stated in the quotation.  The quotation does not claim $f_\beta$ is the density function of any particular random variable: density functions exist and can be defined without reference to random variables.  The quotation is a little sloppy insofar as $f_\beta$ likely is *not* a density: it has to be normalized for that to happen.